# After conversion to PDO data is not displayed at ListView

Tags: php, pdo

I already create an apps that contain ListView. I uses PHP to connect between android and database. FOr now, I use MySQLi and it works. But when I convert to PDO, the data not displayed. I uses 'Log.d' to trace what the data got. Below is the result:

1. MySQLi (No error) - {"data":[{"report_id":19,"task_name":"ngantuk","badgeid":"12345","report_date":"04 Dec 2019",.......
2. PDO (not log show data)

Now, below is current code for MySQLi and PDO

MySQLi

```
<?php 

    require_once 'config.php';

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    $badgeid = $_GET["badgeid"] ?? "";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status FROM report WHERE badgeid = '$badgeid' AND report_status = 'Pending';");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($report_id, $task_name, $badgeid, $report_date, $photo_before, $photo_after, $report_status);

    $task = array(); 

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['report_id'] = $report_id; 
        $temp['task_name'] = $task_name; 
        $temp['badgeid'] = $badgeid;

        $booked = strtotime($report_date);
        $report_date = date("d M Y", $booked);

        $temp['report_date'] = $report_date;
        $temp['photo_before'] = $photo_before;
        $temp['photo_after'] = $photo_after;
        $temp['report_status'] = $report_status; 
        array_push($task, $temp);
    }

    $response = array();
    $response["data"] = $task;
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

PDO

```
    require_once 'configPDO.php';

    $badgeid = $_GET["badgeid"] ?? "";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status FROM report WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND report_status = 'Pending'");   
    $stmt->bindParam(':badgeid',$badgeid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $task = array();

    while ($result) {
        $temp = array();

        $temp["data"] = $task; 
        array_push($task, $temp);
    }   


    $response = array();
    $response["data"] = $result;

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Does anyone know what is problem with my PDO code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysqli code and PDO code are not the same. I copied the code from the mysqli version to the PDO version.

`PDOStatement::fetch()` gets one row at a time. When you take the results from fetch and put it into the condition of a while loop, you are creating an infinite loop which will eventually run out of memory.

```
require_once 'configPDO.php';

$badgeid = $_GET["badgeid"] ?? "";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT report_id, task_name, badgeid, report_date, photo_before, photo_after, report_status FROM report WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND report_status = 'Pending'");   
$stmt->bindParam(':badgeid',$badgeid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$task = [];

while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $temp = [];
    $temp['report_id'] = $result['report_id']; 
    $temp['task_name'] = $result['task_name']; 
    $temp['badgeid'] = $result['badgeid'];

    $booked = strtotime($result['report_date']);
    $report_date = date("d M Y", $booked);

    $temp['report_date'] = $result['report_date'];
    $temp['photo_before'] = $result['photo_before'];
    $temp['photo_after'] = $result['photo_after'];
    $temp['report_status'] = $result['report_status']; 
    $task[] = $temp;
}   


$response = [];
$response["data"] = $task;

echo json_encode($response);
```